# Merge multiple checkboxes groups into one array with javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have form with checkboxes groups, like so:

```html
<input type="checkbox" name="group_one" value="1">
<input type="checkbox" name="group_one" value="2">
<input type="checkbox" name="group_two" value="1">
<input type="checkbox" name="group_two" value="2">
```

What I'm trying to achieve is on form.change() I would like to have an array with keys of checkboxes names and array of the values, like so

```
var checkboxes = $('input').filter(':checked');
var myArray = [];

checkboxes.each(function () {

 var name = $(this).attr('name');
 var val  = $(this).val();

 myArray[name] = val;

});
```

As a result I'm trying to get an array with 'name' as keys and 'val' as an array, like so:

```
[group_one: {1,2}, group_two: {1,2}]
```

I hope this make sense. Thank you for any help in advance!

Comment: Arrays are commonly used for storing data at *integer* indexes, not names like "group_one": in that case it makes more sense to use a plain object, not an array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your desired output should in fact have the array and plain-object notation swapped. The outer structure is a plain object with named keys, while the inner structure is an array of values:

```
{group_one: [1,2], group_two: [1,2]}
```

So you need to initialise the outer structure as a plain object, and maybe name it as plural:

```
var myArrays = {};
```

Then, in your loop, check if you already have a value for the given key. If not, create an array with `[]` and add the value to that. Otherwise, add the value to the array that was already there:

```js
$("form").change(function () {
  var checkboxes = $('input').filter(':checked');
  var myArrays = {};

  checkboxes.each(function () {
    var name = $(this).attr('name');
    var val  = $(this).val();
    if (!(name in myArrays)) myArrays[name] = [];
    myArrays[name].push(val);
  });
  $("pre").text(JSON.stringify(myArrays, null, 2)); // For debugging
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <input type="checkbox" name="group_one" checked value="1">Option 1
  <input type="checkbox" name="group_one"         value="2">Option 2
  <input type="checkbox" name="group_one" checked value="3">Option 3
  <br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="group_two"         value="1">Option 1
  <input type="checkbox" name="group_two" checked value="2">Option 2
  <input type="checkbox" name="group_two" checked value="3">Option 3
</form>
<pre></pre>
```